# How to make Property Tax Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am completely new to JavaScript and my employers would like me to create a Property Tax Calculator.

I know the calculation and I know some of the code I'll need (from researching this for 2 days), but I can't put them together to get it to work. I also need an input field on my page, as the client needs to input their own value to make the calculation work. The calculation is:

Fair Market Value X 45% = Portioned Assessment 
Portioned Assessed value X 30.915/1000 = Gross Taxes

I know I need my function to look kind of like this:

```
function PortionedAssessment() {
    var GrossTax = var FMValue * .45 * .030915;
```

My variables:

```
    var PortAssess;
    var GrossTax;
    var FMValue = document.getElementsByName("FMValue").value;
```

And I have part of my form (no styling done yet, I'll do that afterwards):

```
<form name="PropertyCalc">

    Enter your Fair Market Value: <input type="text" value="FMValue"> X 45% X 0.030915

    <input type="button" onclick="calculate(PortionedAssessment)" name="result" 
    value="Calculate" class="calcButton">

    Gross Taxes = ;

</form>
```

I'm not sure how to put the calculation together or how to input the answer into my form. How do you direct a console.log to a div? I know I'm missing a lot, but like I said, this is completely over my head and I don't know who else to ask.

Comment: We are **not** a code writing service. Your question should include a clear problem or question, and code that is veritably not working correctly, giving us an expected output and an actual output. What have you tried to research? What have you tried so far? [Please review How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is `calculate`?  Another function you have?  You should really include what issue you are having and the minimal code to reproduce that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#Calculate').click(function() {
  var FMValue = document.getElementById('FMValue').value ? document.getElementById('FMValue').value : '0';
  var num = parseInt(FMValue); //convert to int
  var GrossTax = num * .45 * .030915;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = GrossTax; //return value to id of result
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your Fair Market Value: <input type="text" id="FMValue"> X 45% X 0.030915

<button class="calcButton" id="Calculate">Calculate</button>

<div>
  GrossTax:
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Monkey_Dev1300! This helps a lot. I keep having issues though where it is not recognizing my function. `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick` And I'm not really sure why not....I have it in exactly the same manner you have coded it. 
`function calculate() {
//code }` and
`onclick="calculate()"` on my button.

Comment: do you have your js file inside your html file?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's easier with the Wordpress template I have.

Comment: I updated the snippet, see if that works out for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! I'm actually curious as to why it wouldn't work? I see the difference in your code, but how come it has to be written like that? (If you don't have time to answer, that's totally fine, I really appreciate your help!)

Comment: It's best practice to do your click function inside your js file, so instead of using the `onclick` attribute on your `<button>` you can do it in your js file.  Make sure to make it the correction answer (:

Comment: For some reason, you couldn't find the calculate() function, so I used a click function and call your id of the button to execute the method you needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it! That helps me understand a lot more. I really appreciate it! How do I make it the correct answer?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when to call the `calculate` function. I refactored your code a bit. Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
// grab the necessary elements
var input = document.getElementById('fm-input');
var button = document.getElementById('calculate-button');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function calculate (fm) {
  return fm * .45 * .030915;
}

// listen for the 'click' event
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var gross = calculate(input.value); // calculate the gross taxes
  result.textContent = gross; // write the gross value in the <span> element
});
```

```html
<div>
  Enter your Fair Market Value: <input type="number" id="fm-input" placeholder="FMValue"> X 45% X 0.030915
</div>

<div>
  <button id="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
</div>

<div>
  Gross Taxes: <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Monkey_Dev1300 and @PeterMader!

Your answers make a lot of sense! However, I don't just want to take code that I don't understand and use it! I understand grabbing the value by getting the Element by ID, that makes sense. May I ask why you added the '? document.getElementById("FMValue').value: '0';?' 

Everything else makes total sense to me, I just don't know how to write it, but this helps teach me.

Again, thank you for your help, much appreciated!